# How to install Scala on Mac OS X with MacPorts?

Tags: snow-leopard, install, macports

I'm trying to install Scala following the [advice at the official website](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/292#distributions):

```
sudo port install scala
```

But this gives me:

```
--->  Fetching archive for scala
--->  Attempting to fetch scala-2.7.7_2.darwin_10.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/scala
--->  Fetching scala
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for scala
--->  Extracting scala
--->  Configuring scala
Error: Please use one of the numbered scala* ports instead.
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: obsolete port
Log for scala is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_scala/scala/main.log
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

I'm completely new to both MacPorts and Scala, and don't know what "Please use one of the numbered scala* ports instead" means. **What command should I use then?**

I'm not too picky about the Scala version, but of course I'd prefer the latest stable one (currently 2.9.1).

NB: I know I could install Scala without MacPorts, but I'd rather use Macports to manage the installation if it's possible without much hassle.

Comment: Update (2015), just for the record: nowadays I'd prefer **[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)** for installing Scala (and other things) on OS X: `brew install scala`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try installing [Scala 2.9](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/scala2.9/Portfile)

```
sudo port install scala2.9
```

… or [Scala 2.10](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/lang/scala2.10/Portfile)

```
sudo port install scala2.10
```

Answer (score 2):

Your project's SBT config file can be used to download the latest version of Scala -- for the project.  Of course this uses a little extra time for each project you set up, compared to having the latest Scala version installed already.  The advantage is that SBT's repositories are always up to date with Scala releases, unlike Macports.

Answer (score 1):

Now, scala29 is obsolete.  You need to install scala 2.9 or scala2.10:

```
sudo port install scala2.9
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You can always improve existing posts by editing them. There's no need to post another answer for each new version or version change.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is find the latest available version of `scala`. It helps to have recently updated your macports tree:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

Once that is done, [`grep`](http://www.techonthenet.com/unix/basic/grep.php) for scala-related ports:

```
port list | grep scala
```

At the time of this writing, here is sample output from that:

```
$ port list | grep scala
scala-migrations               @1.0.1          java/scala-migrations
scala2.10                      @2.10.5         lang/scala2.10
scala2.10-docs                 @2.10.5         lang/scala2.10
scala2.11                      @2.11.7         lang/scala2.11
scala2.11-docs                 @2.11.7         lang/scala2.11
scala2.7                       @2.7.7          lang/scala2.7
scala2.8                       @2.8.2          lang/scala2.8
scala2.9                       @2.9.3          lang/scala2.9
scala210                       @0.0.2.10.0-M4  lang/scala210
scala27                        @2.7.7          lang/scala27
scala28                        @2.8.2          lang/scala28
scala29                        @2.9.2          lang/scala29
scalapack                      @2.0.2          math/scalapack
p5.8-scalar-list-utils         @1.410.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.10-scalar-list-utils        @1.410.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.12-scalar-list-utils        @1.410.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.14-scalar-list-utils        @1.410.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.8-set-scalar                @1.260.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.10-set-scalar               @1.260.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.12-set-scalar               @1.260.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5.14-set-scalar               @1.260.0        perl/p5-graveyard
p5-scalar-list-utils           @1.420.0        perl/p5-scalar-list-utils
p5.16-scalar-list-utils        @1.420.0        perl/p5-scalar-list-utils
p5.18-scalar-list-utils        @1.420.0        perl/p5-scalar-list-utils
p5.20-scalar-list-utils        @1.420.0        perl/p5-scalar-list-utils
p5.22-scalar-list-utils        @1.420.0        perl/p5-scalar-list-utils
p5-scalar-string               @0.2.0          perl/p5-scalar-string
p5.16-scalar-string            @0.2.0          perl/p5-scalar-string
p5.18-scalar-string            @0.2.0          perl/p5-scalar-string
p5.20-scalar-string            @0.2.0          perl/p5-scalar-string
p5.22-scalar-string            @0.2.0          perl/p5-scalar-string
p5-set-scalar                  @1.290.0        perl/p5-set-scalar
p5.16-set-scalar               @1.290.0        perl/p5-set-scalar
p5.18-set-scalar               @1.290.0        perl/p5-set-scalar
p5.20-set-scalar               @1.290.0        perl/p5-set-scalar
p5.22-set-scalar               @1.290.0        perl/p5-set-scalar
scala_select                   @0.1            sysutils/scala_select
```

You want to look for the basic scala package with the latest (i.e. largest) version number. In this case `scala2.11`. You can [also look here](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=scala), but the list is a little harder to digest. Once you've selected your package, install it like so:

```
sudo port install scala2.11
```

After running this you can confirm it installed with this:

```
ls -la /opt/local/bin/ | grep scala
```

For instance:

```
$ ls -la /opt/local/bin/ | grep scala
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root admin     27 Nov 17 10:54 fsc-2.11 -> ../share/scala-2.11/bin/fsc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root admin     29 Nov 17 10:54 scala-2.11 -> ../share/scala-2.11/bin/scala
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root admin     30 Nov 17 10:54 scalac-2.11 -> ../share/scala-2.11/bin/scalac
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root admin     32 Nov 17 10:54 scaladoc-2.11 -> ../share/scala-2.11/bin/scaladoc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root admin     30 Nov 17 10:54 scalap-2.11 -> ../share/scala-2.11/bin/scalap
```

Now you're most of the way there. The last thing you want to do is `select` the current version of `scala`. Currently no version is selected and you can show this with the following command:

```
$ sudo port select --list scala
Available versions for scala:
    none (active)
    scala2.11
```

This says that `scala2.11` is installed but no version is selected. To select a version run this (though you want to substitute in the version you actually installed):

```
$ sudo port select --set scala scala2.11
Selecting 'scala2.11' for 'scala' succeeded. 'scala2.11' is now active.
```

And showing it's now selected:

```
$ sudo port select --list scala
Available versions for scala:
    none
    scala2.11 (active)
$ which scala
/opt/local/bin/scala
```